# How to display HTTPBuilder logs in groovyConsole

Tags: logging, groovy, httpbuilder, groovy-2

### The Problem

I'm getting `groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException: Not Found` and want to see the logs from `HTTPBuilder`. I'm using **Groovy 2.1.9** with `groovyConsole`.

### What I tried

So I checked [this blog post](http://blog.techstacks.com/2009/12/configuring-wire-logging-in-groovy-httpbuilder.html) that says about adding `log4j.xml` to `groovy.home/conf/`. I did that, here's my file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %-5p  %c{1} - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="groovyx.net.http">
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
    </category>

    <!-- Use DEBUG to see basic request/response info;  
         Use TRACE to see headers for HttpURLClient. -->
    <category name="groovyx.net.http.HttpURLClient">
        <priority value="INFO" />
    </category>

    <category name="org.apache.http">
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
    </category>
    <category name="org.apache.http.headers">
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
    </category>
    <category name="org.apache.http.wire">
        <priority value="DEBUG" />
    </category>

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

And here's my script that I'm running in the console:

```
import groovyx.net.http.*
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager
import java.security.SecureRandom
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry

import groovy.util.logging.*

@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.6')
@Grab( 'log4j:log4j:1.2.16' )
@Log4j
class WebserviceTest {
  static void main (String[] args) {

    def http = new HTTPBuilder('https://localhost:8443/project/service/')
    log.debug "http is instanceof ${http.getClass()}" //this is printed

    //=== SSL UNSECURE CERTIFICATE ===
   def sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")              
   sslContext.init(null, [ new X509TrustManager() {
     public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {null}
     public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
     public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) { }
   } ] as TrustManager[], new SecureRandom())
   def sf = new SSLSocketFactory(sslContext, SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
   def httpsScheme = new Scheme("https", sf, 4483)
   http.client.connectionManager.schemeRegistry.register( httpsScheme )
   //================================

    //the next line throws the exeption...
    http.post(path: '/method', contentType: ContentType.JSON, query: [param: '1000']) { resp, reader ->
        println "resp is instanceof ${resp.getClass()}"
        println "and reader is instanceof ${reder.getClass()}"

        println "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
        println 'Headers: -----------'
        resp.headers.each { h ->
          println " ${h.name} : ${h.value}"
        }
        println 'Response data: -----'
        System.out << reader
        println '\n--------------------'

    }
  } 
}
```

**EDIT**: my HttpResponseException is solved, I had a `/` unnecessary in the request, but still no builder logs appearing.

Comment: Here's how I got it to log using `java.util.logging` instead of `log4j`: http://www.redtoad.ca/ataylor/2013/10/logging-httpbuilder-traffic/

Answer (score 2):

`HTTPBuilder` uses commons-logging, so you have to bridge the output from commons-logging to log4j. Unfortunately log4j 1.2 doesn't support this out of the box. So I simplified your example and switched to [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/), which is a 'Simple Logging Facade for Java'. Under the hood the following config still uses log4j, so you still need your `log4j.xml` in place (`groovy.home/conf/`). For a detailled explanation see [Bridging legacy APIs](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.6'),
    // This brings in slf4j, log4j12 (as dependancies) and the bridge to log4j
    @Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-log4j12', version='1.7.7'),
    // This brings in the bridge to commons-logging
    @Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='jcl-over-slf4j', version='1.7.7')
])

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import groovyx.net.http.*

// get a logger for the script
def log = LoggerFactory.getLogger('script')

def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://www.google.com')
log.info "http is instanceof ${http.getClass()}" //this is printed

http.get( path : '/search', contentType : ContentType.TEXT, query : [q:'Groovy'] ) { resp, reader ->
    log.debug "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
    println 'Done'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Import this

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
```

And Set

```
Logger rootLogger = (Logger)LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME)
rootLogger.setLevel(mLevel)
```

You can set this before the HTTP builder gets called